# ¿Cómo llamar procedimiento almacenado de inserción, desde PHP bajo modelo MVC?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, mvc, stored-procedure

Intento insertar registros en MySQL desde un formulario usando PHP y usando un modelo MVC, los datos son enviados con Ajax, para ser procesados por otro archivo:

Los archivos empleados son los siguientes:

Archivo de conexiones para retornar consultas: Clase Conexion

```
function ejecutarConsulta($sql)
{
    global $conexion;
    $query = $conexion->query($sql);
    return $query;
}
```

Archivo de Modelo, Clase Alumno

```
public function insertar($matricula,$curp,$nombre,$direccion,$telefono,$estado)
{
    $sql="CALL sp_inserta_Alumno($matricula,'$curp','$nombre','$direccion','$telefono',$estado)";
    return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
}
```

Archivo que procesa los datos,

```
<?php 
require_once "../modelos/Alumno.php";
$alumno=new Alumno();
$idalumno=isset($_POST["idalumno"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["idalumno"]):"";
$matricula=isset($_POST["matricula"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["matricula"]):"";
$curp=isset($_POST["curp"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["curp"]):"";
$nombre=isset($_POST["nombre"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["nombre"]):"";
$direccion=isset($_POST["direccion"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["direccion"]):"";
$telefono=isset($_POST["telefono"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["telefono"]):"";
$estado=isset($_POST["estado"])? limpiarCadena($_POST["estado"]):"";

switch ($_GET["op"]){
case 'guardaryeditar':

    if (empty($idalumno)){
        $rspta=$alumno->insertar($matricula,$curp,$nombre,$direccion,$telefono,$estado);
        echo $rspta ? "Alumno registrado" : "Alumno no se pudo registrar";
    }
    else {
        $rspta=$articulo->editar($matricula,$curp,$nombre,$direccion,$telefono,$estado);
        echo $rspta ? "Alumno actualizado" : "Alumno no se pudo actualizar";
    }
break;
```

Archivo ajax, que envía los datos al archivo de procesamiento.

```
function guardaryeditar(e)
{
e.preventDefault(); //No se activará la acción predeterminada del evento`
$("#btnGuardar").prop("disabled",true);
var formData = new FormData($("#formulario")[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: "../ajax/alumno.php?op=guardaryeditar",
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,

    success: function(datos)
    {                    
          bootbox.alert(datos);           
          mostrarform(false);
          tabla.ajax.reload();
    }

});
limpiar();
}
```

El problema es que no esta insertando el registro y en el archivo de procesamiento esta entrando en esta condición else: No se pudo registrar

```
echo $rspta ? "Alumno registrado" : "Alumno no se pudo registrar";
```

Comment: Lo primero sería verificar qué estás pasando y organizado de qué manera en `formData`. Depura con un `console.log(formData);`  y dinos lo que ves en la consola de Javascript. Luego, parecería que tienes cosas al revés en tu lógica. Yo informaría el objeto `Alumno`  con los datos recibidos y luego mandaría a insertar el objeto ya lleno con sus propiedades. Así, el método `insertar` pasaría a otra capa de tu aplicación, no quedando amarrado a la clase `Alumno` lo cual realmente no tiene mucho sentido desde el punto de vista la POO, pero ese es otro asunto.

Comment: Otra cosa es que estás usando `GET`  aquí: `switch ($_GET["op"]){`, pero el método es `POST`, a veces usar `GET` funciona aunque hayas enviado por POST, pero lo correcto es usar siempre el método que has indicado del lado de Ajax. Considera también actualizar tu código Ajax, por ejemplo, `type`  es absoleto, deberías usar ahora `method`, también  `success` es obsoleto, y deberías usar `done`. Lo comento aquí para que lo tengas en cuenta una vez hayas resuelto el problema principal.